# Area, perimeter and other geometric parameters of a "cucumber"

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, area

From the simulation, I have got a region with a shape of a cucumber. Here are the boundary points of this region:

```
    points={{-51.8154, -7.87585}, {-51.4981, -9.07511}, {-50.7058, -10.0832},
{-49.6018, -4.74619}, {-48.2803, -11.4124}, {-46.9928, -3.77299}, 
{-45.6489, -3.47276}, {-44.2639, -3.22895}, {-42.9397, -3.03183}, 
{-41.6458, -12.5322}, {-40.2702, -2.69045}, {-39.0344, -12.7406}, 
{-37.8018, -2.40687}, {-36.818, -2.29835}, {-35.9484, -2.20398}, 
{-35.0946, -12.9759}, {-34.3388, -2.03227}, {-33.6244, -13.0436}, 
{-32.8205, -13.0758}, {-32.2143, -1.81073}, {-31.4414, -1.73128}, 
{-30.8024, -13.1417}, {-30.0715, -13.1596}, {-29.3826, -1.52292},
{-28.6861, -13.1843}, {-27.9978, -1.38513}, {-27.2845, -1.3149}, 
{-26.6671, -13.198}, {-25.9167, -13.1964}, {-25.2951, -13.1905}, 
{-24.6382, -1.05904}, {-24.0118, -0.999494}, {-23.4113, -13.1551}, 
{-22.7873, -13.1362}, {-22.2145, -0.831418}, {-21.5221, -13.0863}, 
{-20.9788, -13.0602}, {-20.318, -0.658561}, {-19.6075, -0.595113}, 
{-18.9253, -0.53477}, {-18.2165, -12.8715}, {-17.4521, -12.802}, 
{-16.7627, -12.7321}, {-16.0979, -12.657}, {-15.4264, -0.238117}, 
{-14.7891, -0.186553}, {-14.199, -12.4019}, {-13.574, -0.0910152}, 
{-12.9683, -12.1993}, {-12.4449, -12.1037}, {-11.8628, -11.9896}, 
{-11.3199, -11.8752}, {-10.7885, -11.7561}, {-10.2664, 
  0.14807}, {-9.74814, 0.181988}, {-9.25385, 
  0.21326}, {-8.74659, -11.2211}, {-8.2975, 0.270548}, {-7.84554, 
  0.295845}, {-7.28951, -10.7513}, {-6.82029, -10.5812}, {-6.33469, 
  0.370455}, {-5.74863, 0.394195}, {-5.21578, 
  0.412767}, {-4.67071, -9.66011}, {-4.15673, 0.438426}, {-3.65182, 
  0.444119}, {-3.14881, 0.44327}, {-2.64409, 
  0.43725}, {-2.11111, -8.13303}, {-1.47669, 0.380331}, {-0.810045, 
  0.305888}, {-0.199921, -6.4323}, {0.499229, -5.55786}, {1.07042, 
-0.372346}, {1.4821, -3.60779}};
```

My idea was to transform them to a mesh

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`    
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[points];
    emesh=ToElementMesh[bmesh];
```

and to apply then measures such as `Area[emesh]`.
The first step works to an extent:

```
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

returns the following image of the "cucumber":

[image]

Further, however, it does not work. If I make

```
Area[bmesh]
```

I get the following message: "ElementMesh[<<1>>] is not a correctly specified region"
If I try to make the `ElementMesh`

```
emesh=ToElementMesh[bmesh]
```

the Kernel stops working.

**My question**: Do you see a workaround to either make a mesh or use a different approach?

Comment: Perhaps `MeshRegion[emesh]` is the workaround you are looking for. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ConvexHullRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullRegion.html)

```
rgn = ConvexHullRegion[points]
```

[image]

```
Region[rgn]
```

[image]

```
Area[rgn]

(* 545.429 *)

Perimeter[rgn]

(* 116.614 *)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's fine.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to Bob's nice answer use `FindShortestTour` if the shape isn't convex

```
index = FindShortestTour[points][[2]];
shape= Polygon[points[[index]]]

Area[shape]      (*545.429*) 
Perimeter[shape] (*116.614*)
```

**addendum**

`MeshRegion` makes your approach using FEM-mesh work

```
MeshRegion[emesh] // Area      (*545.429*) 
MeshRegion[emesh] // Perimeter (*116.614*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 13.0 we also have a solution for the case when the cucumber is concave.

```
points={{-51.81,-7.87},{-51.49,-9.07},{-50.7,-10.08},{-49.60,-4.74},
{-48.28,-11.41},{-41.64,-12.53},{-35.09,-12.97},{-20.97,-13.06},{-16.76,-12.73},
{-12.44,-12.1},{-8.74,-11.22},{-6.82,-10.58},{-2.11,-8.13},{-0.81,1.805},
{-0.199,-6.43},{1.07,-0.372},{1.48,-3.607},{-44.6,-4.9},{-39.3,-5.9},
{-34.4,-6.9},{-26.3,-7.0},{-18.5,-5.6},{-11.7,-0.9},{-6.7,1.2},{-28.2,-13.2}};
reg=ConcaveHullMesh[points]
```

[image: displayed mesh]

```
Area[reg]
(* 407.329 *)
```